# when to use AWS sync client vs AWS Async client

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs

I am trying to utilize AWS services like SQS and DynamoDB,

AWS provides async clients ( java ) for both AWS SQS and DynamoDB and many more.
I am able to do basic operations via both clients.

What is the difference between the two clients , so I can decide to choose which client to move ahead with.

```
AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB = new AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
or
AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
```

Comment: What is the doubt here? If you need asyc then you use the async client or wrap the sync client with thread pools to get poor-man's-async-client. If you need sync then you use sync client. As simple as that.

Comment: Whether you use Async or Sync client - you should be using Amazon DynamoDB V2 API, not V1. V2 examples are here in the Java V2 DEV Guide. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-dynamodb.html

Comment: @sarveshseri : i dont understand what sync async means here

Comment: @user1379280 if you don't know the difference you probably want sync

Comment: There are lots of resources online that describe the difference between synchronous and asynchronous operations.  Here's a popular post on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/748189/13549664